# Elasticsearch query a specific node for scroll

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a scan/scroll query where each document that comes back has something done to it and is then the changes are written back.  Basically mapping over the whole index (or document type actually).

If the function applied during this mapping starts to become too slow then I need to find a way to split this across several machines.

I could share a scroll ID across multiple machines using Zookeeper or something but will there be issues querying ES from 2 clients at almost the same time?

Alternatively, is there a way to write a query that will only run against one specified node?  This way, if I had one 'mapping process' on the same box as one node then I could remove the network overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Check "_only_node" or "_prefer_node" option in [ElasticSearch API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html).